# How to generate PDF record dynamicaly using php

Tags: php, html, pdf

I would to display record dynamically in PDF but static data(HTML) will be display and php variable will displayed either blank screen or 1. ex. $head  variable.

```
 <?php
 require_once("includes/config.php");
 $Admin = new admins;
 $performance = $Admin->select($Admin->performance,'',"id=".$_GET['id']);
 $head = $performance[0]['research_head'];

 $url = 'http://freehtmltopdf.com';
 $data = array('convert' => '','html' => '<html><head><title>Invesys Capital</title>
</head>
<body>
*****<div>'.print_r($head).'</div>*****         
</body>
</html>
','baseurl' => 'http://technobratz.in/invesyscapital/');

// use key 'http' even if you send the request to https://...
$options = array(
    'http' => array(
        'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'content' => http_build_query($data),
    ),
);
$context  = stream_context_create($options);
$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

// set the pdf data as download content:
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="webpage.pdf"');
var_dump($result);

?>
```

Comment: To begin with, `var_dump()` is by no means designed to produce PDF at all.

Comment: Its working now just pass variable instead of echo and print